# IOExeption when crawling with nutch

Tags: web-crawler, nutch, ioexception

After one day crawling with nutch(1.4) ... at last i got the bad bad below exception:

```
.
.
.

-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=0
-activeThreads=0, spinWaiting=0, fetchQueues.totalSize=0
-activeThreads=0
Fetcher: java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1252)
    at org.apache.nutch.fetcher.Fetcher.fetch(Fetcher.java:1204)
    at org.apache.nutch.fetcher.Fetcher.run(Fetcher.java:1240)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.fetcher.Fetcher.main(Fetcher.java:1213)
.
.
```

.

i have 20 news site and input argument of nutch is : depth 3 and topN -1
i have enough space in root directory of my linux and about 4GB of ram
how can i solve this issue?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you might have this problem: http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchGotchas

The answer provided there states:

> The answer we find addressed the situation is that you're most likely out of disk space in /tmp. Consider using another location, or possibly another partition for hadoop.tmp.dir (which can be set in nutch-site.xml) with plenty of room for large transient files or using a Hadoop cluster.

Comment: I have specified the great space to my /tmp but nothing changed and the same exception occur.is there any misconfiguration?

Comment: I'm not sure what else can be wrong, but can you make sure that you have not ran out of space anyway? See how much data you have in the tmp folder and confirm that you don't have more than the space you've specified.